# ASP.NET Repeater User Control DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that contains a repeater. It seems that data cannot be assigned to it's DataSource property, I have tried a few different data sources but the following error is displayed: (I have debugged it and there are data items in the datasource)

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here's the aspx for the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I create an instance of the user control in the code behind of the file I want to display the repeater in - I can't type repeater1.DataSource and assign it in that page so I added an attribute to the user control which takes IEnumerable as the datasource.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: where do you assign the datasource to the repeater? If you cannot assign it from your page because the repeater control is inside a user control, create a method like SetDataSource in the user control and you pass a datasource to that method from your page and that method will assign it to the repeater.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do such things in the `DataBind()` method like shown below:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
   this.repeater.DataSource = ...
   this.repeater.DataBind();
   ...
}
```

So it will bind whilst parent page calling `Page.DataBind()` as well

[Control.DataBind Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx):

> Use this method to bind data from a source to a server control. This
>   method is commonly used after retrieving a dataset through a database
>   query. Most controls perform data binding automatically, which means
>   that you typically do not need to call this method explicitly.

Comment: The error still occurs even though the data source contains items. The override method doesn't seem to be being called.

Comment: I don't understand how it can display this error when the datasource is being set with an object that contains data?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser : are you sure that problem is with repeater? Can you enable CLR exceptions in the Debug -> Exceptions VS Menu and run in debug mode (or attach debugger to w3wp.exe process) and see pwerhaps the problem in an other place

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Inside the user controls where is the repeater located, in the OnLoad() method

do this :

```
 repeater1.DataSource = MyIEnumerableProperty;
 repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried that but it errors on the line where the DataSource is set.